# Is it considered unprofessional to have a funky e-mail address?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, resume, email, unprofessional-behavior

I have an e-mail address that ends in **0609**. I have heard that to look professional(during interviews,in your resume, CV etc), you need to have an e-mail address that sounds professional, like using your name or some other information instead of slang words like dude_134_xyz ,cool_boy( yes these kind of e-mail addresses exist! ). If yes, does my e-mail address(*some_characters* **0609**@gmail.com) sounds unprofessional. People may interpret 0609 as 69 which is something I need not to specify, which in turn may show unprofessional-ism. Actually, they are two dates of some significance to me.
P.S. :- I am not ready to update my e-mail address. It is going to be a cumbersome task.

Comment: Relevant YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbcJLqWgxTA (but I've not got enough to say to make this a proper answer).

Comment: You can create a new address and have it forward to your old account. Then you can have a professional address but not have to change your current address.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a job, the best option is :
firstName.familyName@something.com

If this email is already taken because of homonyms, you can try something like:
pro-firstName.familyName@something.com

For the HR it is more convenient to contact you if your email adress fit your names informations. Any other information can be misleading for the HR, or can put their mind on something else and somehow give a bad opinion about you.

Your email is:
some_characters 0609@gmail.com
It is not really unprofessional ( as dude_134_xyz), but if it is too complicated or too long the HR can makes mistake in it and you can never receive news from them.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of security in the IT sector, I would not consider a "funky" email address to be unprofessional.

While it does make sense to have an email address that people can easily remember, you do not want to have an email address that has identifying information included in it, such as the usual Firstname/LastName/DateOfBirth@XXX.YYY

Hope that helps.